# Filter core-list elements by string match

Tags: javascript, polymer

Simple filter that will hide any item in `core-list` that doesn't match the entered string. The filtered elements will have property 'hidden', hence they should not take any space... Obviously there is something wrong and probably `core-list` has something to do with it. Also when filter is applied and scrolling down then go back up reveals all the elements again :/ Any idea of how can make this filter working with `core-list`? For this sample i've made the filter to match the name for every list item.

```html
<script src="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-list/core-list.html">

<my-element></my-element>

<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
      :host core-list {
        margin: 8px 0;
        height: 400px;
        width: 350px;
      }
      :host core-list div {
        border: 1px solid #008000;
      }
    </style>

    <label for="s">Search:</label>
    <input id="s" value="{{ filtervalue }}">

    <core-list id="list" data="{{ arr }}" height="50">
      <template>
        <div hidden?="{{ filtervalue | filter(model) }}">
          Name: {{ model.name }}, Index: {{ index }}, Selected: {{ selected }}
        </div>
      </template>
    </core-list>
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      function genData() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          arr.push({
            name: "sample" + i,
            pos: i
          });
        }
        return arr;
      }

      Polymer('my-element', {
        created: function() {
          this.arr = genData();
        },
        ready: function() {},
        filter: function(v, model) {
          if (!v) return false;

          if (model) {
            console.log("v: %o\n%o", v, model.name);
            return model.name.indexOf(v) < 0;
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Here are some filters that maybe can help:
https://github.com/addyosmani/polymer-filters/blob/master/filter-startsWith.js

Filters are referenced from here:
https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#examples

Comment: That works really good. Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8aLupm2z/ I don't know how i've missed that... Thanks :) If you submit that as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes as an answer:

Here are some filters that can help: [polymer-filters/filter-startsWith.js](https://github.com/addyosmani/polymer-filters/blob/master/filter-startsWith.js)

Filters are referenced from [Polymer expressions examples](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#examples).